# How to create function that cut a string from certain position and put it in front of the same string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let’s say I have this:

```
   text = “ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ”
   letter = “N”

   new_text = function(text, letter)

   print(new_text)
```

Is is possible to create a function that the output is

```
NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Short answer: Yes, it is possible to do this. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] showing what you have tried so far based on your own research so that we can better understand how to give specific help

Answer (score 1):

With [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> left, letter, right = text.partition(letter)
>>> out = letter + right + left
>>> out
"NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
text[text.find('N'):] + text[: text.find('N')]
```

'NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM'